# Inserting values into a numpy array based on values in that array

Tags: python, numpy

If I have an array:

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3]])
```

I can add a value to this array based on the values inside the array.

```
a = np.insert(a,3,(0.299+a[0][1]*0.587+a[0][2]*0.114))
```

This would give me the following array.

```
array([1, 2, 3, 1.815])
```

So far so good. But now I want to do this for an array with the following shape.

```
a = np.array(
    [
        [[1,2,3],[3,4,5]],
        [[6,7,8],[9,10,11]]
    ])

array([[[ 1,  2,  3],
        [ 3,  4,  5]],

       [[ 6,  7,  8],
        [ 9, 10, 11]]])
```

Is there any way to do this without using a for-loop?

**EDIT** Orginal question has a 'minimal working example' that was too much simplified, resulting in the use of the np.sum() function. Now it follows the following formula, that I need (0.299*R + 0.587*G+ 0.114*B)

Comment: `np.concatenate((X, X.sum(2, keepdims=True)), 2)`?

Comment: I concur that `np.concatenate` is the way to go here. See my answer for your specific formula.

Comment: Not a useful comment, but still happy that my 100th answer on the site was this particular one. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a for loop...well you will have to be iterating over items, so you cannot avoid it I am afraid. Or at least replicating the behavior.

The following will hopefully bring you a step closer to your actual application:

```
#Define a function to apply to the matrix
def f(x, ar):
    return np.append(next(ar),x[0]*0.299+x[1]*0.587+x[2]*0.114)

#Create an iterator for semi-efficient stepping through the matrix elements
b = iter(a.reshape((a.shape[0]*a.shape[1],-1)))

#create output array; syntax:
#np.apply_along_axis(1D-function,axis_to_apply_along,object_to_apply_to,optional_arguments)
vals = np.apply_along_axis(f,2,a,b)

#vals
#Out[440]: 
#array([[[  1.   ,   2.   ,   3.   ,   1.815],
#        [  3.   ,   4.   ,   5.   ,   3.815]],
#
#       [[  6.   ,   7.   ,   8.   ,   6.815],
#        [  9.   ,  10.   ,  11.   ,   9.815]]])
```

However, a for loop calls `iter()` on the to-loop-over sequence, and uses `next()` calls on the result. Thus, the above functionality basically implements a for loop in an alternate way. The only thing we have now hopefully changed is that we avoid looping over the wrong things, therefore saving some time in the end..

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify the desired output but I assume this is what you want:

```
a = np.insert(a, 3, a.sum(axis=-1), axis=-1)
a
#[[[ 1  2  3  6]
#  [ 3  4  5 12]]
#
# [[ 6  7  8 21]
#  [ 9 10 11 30]]]
```

Comment: This is the desired output. Yet, in my question I used the sum as a simple example. In actuality what I need is a multiplication of the 1st,2nd and 3rd item (0.299*A + 0.587*B+ 0.114*C). Where `A,B,C` are the 1st,2nd,3rd number per element. I'll update my question.

Answer (score 1):

You may try:

```
a = np.array([[[1,2,3],[3,4,5]],[[6,7,8],[9,10,11]]]).astype(np.float_)
a = np.concatenate((a, 0.299*a[:,:,0:1] + 0.587 * a[:,:,1:2] + 0.114*a[:,:,2:3]), axis = 2 )
```

This gives me:

```
array([[[  1.   ,   2.   ,   3.   ,   1.815],
        [  3.   ,   4.   ,   5.   ,   3.815]],
       [[  6.   ,   7.   ,   8.   ,   6.815],
        [  9.   ,  10.   ,  11.   ,   9.815]]])
```

**NB:** If you need single precision, use `np.float32` instead of `np.float_`, which really corresponds to double precision ([reference for numpy types here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html)). And of course, if `a` already has the right type, no need for conversion.